# awk - check if file contains certain string - if it does find and replace another one

Tags: awk, sed

So i have a file like this:

```
COD:'Anschlag 15'

LET: DimX(2240)
LET: DimZ(1193)
LET: DimS(1.25)
LET: Schenkel(96)


DIM: X DimX+0.5
     Z DimZ+0.5
     S DimS
     STAINLESS
     
REF: X1  FOD-107.69
     X2  FOD-107.69  
     Z1  FOD
     Z2  FOD
     N
ZPF 40
     
MCM: QSU 10 QSD 10
     MNP_SPEED 20

     BLHINH 50
ROT: S 4 ROTONBLH   SPEED 20
    BEN: L 15       AC -1           
    BEN: L Schenkel AC -1
ROT: S 2  ROTONBLH SPEED 20          
    BEN: L 15       AC -1           
    BEN: L Schenkel AC -1               
        
ROT: S 1  ROTONBLH SPEED 20          
    BEN: L 15       AC -1           
    BEN: L Schenkel AC -1                            

 
                                    
ROT: S 3  ROTONBLH SPEED 20          
    BEN-: L 15      AC -1           
    BEN: L 107  AC -1       
        
END: SPEED 40
```

I want to check if the file contains the String **"STAINLESS"**

- if it does
  search for all occurences of **AC -1** and *replace* them with **AC 3**
- if it doesn't contain STAINLESS
  keep the file as it is

What i've tried is:

```
find C:/Users/user/test -type f -exec awk -i inplace -f C:/Users/user/test_skript/b.awk {} +
```

The file b.awk

```
$1 == "STAINLESS" { f = 1 }
if ( f == 1 )
{ gsub(/AC[[:blank:]]*-1/,"AC 3"); print }
else
{ print }
```

The gsub function itself works. But the STAINLESS check doesn't.

Comment: Will `STAINLESS` always come before `AC -1` ?

Comment: Yes, it will always come before AC -1

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, could you please try following, written and tested in GNU `awk`. This should work irrespective of if STAINLESS word comes before AC -1 or after it.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/STAINLESS/){ found=1 }
  next
}
found{
  gsub(/AC -1/,"AC 3")
}
1
' Input_file Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                               ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                            ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when first time Input_file is being read.
  if($0~/STAINLESS/){ found=1 }     ##Checking condition if line contains STAINLESS then set found to 1 here.
  next                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found{                              ##Checking condition if found is SET then do following.
  gsub(/AC -1/,"AC 3")              ##Globally substituting AC -1 with AC 3 here.
}
1                                   ##Mentioning 1 will print line here.
' Input_file Input_file             ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

***NOTE:*** Also change `if($0~/STAINLESS/){ found=1 }`  TO `if($0~/STAINLESS/){ found=1; nextfile}` in case you have GNU `awk`, to make it faster in running time wise.

Answer (score 3):

If `STAINLESS` always comes before `AC -1` then following single pass awk should work:

```sh
awk '/STAINLESS/{f=1} f{gsub(/AC -1/, "AC 3")} 1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is based on the OPs requirements:

> I want to check if the file contains the String "STAINLESS"
>
> ```
> if it does search for all occurences of AC -1 and replace them with AC 3
> if it doesn't contain STAINLESS keep the file as it is
> ```

and as such:

1. Searches the whole file for `STAINLESS` before replacing `AC -1` with `AC 3` anywhere it occurs in  the file - before, after or on the same line as `STAINLESS`.
2. Will **keep the file as it is** if STAINLESS doesn't exist in it, i.e. does not write to it at all and so won't change the timestamp, ownership, or permissions of it.

Since you're using this in the context of a `find` with `inplace` editing, you need something like this (uses GNU awk for `-i inplace`, `nextfile` and `ENDFILE`):

```
find ... -exec awk -i inplace '
    BEGIN {
        tgt = "STAINLESS"
        ARGV[ARGC++] = ARGV[1]
        inplace::enable = 0
        gotTgt = 0
    }
    ARGIND % 2 {
        if ( $1 == tgt ) {
            gotTgt = 1
            nextfile
        }
        next
    }
    ENDFILE {
        inplace::enable = gotTgt
        gotTgt = 0
    }
    inplace::enable {
        gsub(/AC[[:blank:]]*-1/,"AC 3")
        print
    }
' {} \;
```

The `\;` instead of `+` at the end of the `find` command is important so awk just gets fed one file at a time to make it easiest to do two passes of each file, first to find STAINLESS and then to do the replacement if it was found on the first pass.

Note that we need to set the `enable` flag for the upcoming file in the `ENDFILE` section of the preceding file because by the time `BEGNIFILE` is executed for the upcoming file it's too late, the inplace editing has already been established for that file so if you do a `print "foo"` in a `BEGINFILE` awk knows where to direct it.

Answer (score 0):

if the search string doesn't precede the replacement string, it's easier with `grep/sed` pair.

```
$ grep -q STAINLESS file && sed 's/AC -1/AC 3/g' file
```